# want to get rid of the gap between \mathcal{F} and \mid_S

Tags: formatting

With this code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
```

\begin{document}

$L^{2}(\mathcal{F})\cong L^{2}(\Gamma)\otimes 
L^2(\mathcal{F}\mid_{S})\cong L^{2}(\Gamma) \otimes
L^2(\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma})$

\end{document}

how do I get rid of the gap between the F and the \mid_S ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\mid` gives thick space on both sides. So, instead of `\mid` use `\vert` to get the needed right spacing as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath}

\begin{document}
$L^{2}(\mathcal{F})\cong L^{2}(\Gamma)\otimes 
L^2(\mathcal{F}\vert_{S})\cong L^{2}(\Gamma) \otimes
L^2(\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma})$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]